# How to add a field to a Model in Prisma GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, graphql, prisma

I followed this tutorial from DigitalOcean on how to create a prisma GraphQL API.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-graphql-api-with-prisma-and-deploy-to-digitalocean-s-app-platform

The App is accessing the PostgreSQL database hosted on digitalOcean and everything is working fine.
Now I would like to add the field "test" to the "Post" model:
TypeDefs:

```
  type Post {
    content: String
    id: ID!
    published: Boolean!
    title: String!
    author: User
    test: String

  }
```

Resolver:

```
Mutation: {
    createMeme: (parent, args) => {
      return prisma.post.create({
        data: {
          title: args.title,
          content: args.content,
          published: args.published,
          author: args.authorEmail && {
            connect: { email: args.authorEmail },
          },
          test: args.test,
          
        },
      })
    },
```

Mutation:

```
  type Mutation {
    createMeme(authorEmail: String, content: String, title: String!, published: Boolean, test: String): Post!
  }
```

Model in schema.prisma file:

```
model Post {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  content   String?
  published Boolean @default(false)
  author    User?   @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  Int?
  test      String?
}
```

When I migrate it to my local PostgreSQL database hosted on docker it is working fine, here is what I do:

1. Change DATABASE_URL in .env file to local database
2. Execute: "npm prisma migrate dev"
3. "npm start"

When I now try to change DATABASE_URL to my PostgreSQL Database hosted on digitalOcean I do the following:

1. "git add ."
2. "git commit -m "test field added""
3. "git push"
4. "npx prisma migrate deploy"

In this case I got the following error:
Error: P3018

> A migration failed to apply. New migrations cannot be applied before
> the error is recovered from. Read more about how to resolve migration
> issues in a production database:

I fixed it with "npx prisma migrate reset"

When I now try to excecute the following query against my PostgreSQL database hosted on digital ocean:

```
mutation{
  createMeme(title: "Help", content: "Hellp", published: true, test: "Test") {
    id
    title
    content
    published
    test
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
  {"errors": [
    {
      "message": "\nInvalid `prisma.post.create()` invocation in\n/workspace/src/schema.js:61:26\n\n   58 },\n   59 Mutation: {\n   60   createMeme: (parent, args) => {\n→  61     return prisma.post.create({\n            data: {\n              title: 'Help',\n              content: 'Hellp',\n              published: true,\n              author: undefined,\n              test: 'Test'\n              ~~~~\n            }\n          })\n\nUnknown arg `test` in data.test for type PostCreateInput. Did you mean `title`? Available args:\ntype PostCreateInput {\n  title: String\n  content?: String | Null\n  published?: Boolean\n  author?: UserCreateNestedOneWithoutPostsInput\n}\n\n",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createMeme"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "clientVersion": "3.6.0",
          "stacktrace": [
            "Error: ",
            "Invalid `prisma.post.create()` invocation in",
            "/workspace/src/schema.js:61:26",
            "",
            "   58 },",
            "   59 Mutation: {",
            "   60   createMeme: (parent, args) => {",
            "→  61     return prisma.post.create({",
            "            data: {",
            "              title: 'Help',",
            "              content: 'Hellp',",
            "              published: true,",
            "              author: undefined,",
            "              test: 'Test'",
            "              ~~~~",
            "            }",
            "          })",
            "",
            "Unknown arg `test` in data.test for type PostCreateInput. Did you mean `title`? Available args:",
            "type PostCreateInput {",
            "  title: String",
            "  content?: String | Null",
            "  published?: Boolean",
            "  author?: UserCreateNestedOneWithoutPostsInput",
            "}",
            "",
            "",
            "    at Object.validate (/workspace/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34750:20)",
            "    at PrismaClient._executeRequest (/workspace/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39729:17)",
            "    at consumer (/workspace/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39670:23)",
            "    at /workspace/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39674:49",
            "    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (async_hooks.js:189:9)",
            "    at PrismaClient._request (/workspace/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39674:27)",
            "    at request (/workspace/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39779:77)",
            "    at _callback (/workspace/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39987:14)",
            "    at PrismaPromise.then (/workspace/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39994:23)",
            "    at resolveField (/workspace/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:468:26)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Such a weird behaviour, why is it working on my localhost but not on the digitalocean hosted db?
Am I missing some steps in the terminal? Maybe some commands to execute?

Here is the whole schema.js file with all resolvers, typeDefs etc:

```
    const { gql } = require('apollo-server')
const { prisma } = require('./db')

const typeDefs = gql`
  type User {
    email: String!
    id: ID!
    name: String
    posts: [Post!]!
  }

  type Post {
    content: String
    id: ID!
    published: Boolean!
    title: String!
    author: User
    test: String

  }

  type Query {
    feed: [Post!]!
    post(id: ID!): Post
  }

  type Mutation {
    createUser(data: UserCreateInput!): User!
    createMeme(authorEmail: String, content: String, title: String!, published: Boolean, test: String): Post!
    publish(id: ID!): Post
  }

  input UserCreateInput {
    email: String!
    name: String
    posts: [PostCreateWithoutAuthorInput!]
  }

  input PostCreateWithoutAuthorInput {
    content: String
    published: Boolean
    title: String!
  }
`

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    feed: (parent, args) => {
      return prisma.post.findMany({
        where: { published: true },
      })
    },
    post: (parent, args) => {
      return prisma.post.findOne({
        where: { id: Number(args.id) },
      })
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    createMeme: (parent, args) => {
      return prisma.post.create({
        data: {
          title: args.title,
          content: args.content,
          published: args.published,
          author: args.authorEmail && {
            connect: { email: args.authorEmail },
          },
          test: args.test,
          
        },
      })
    },
    publish: (parent, args) => {
      return prisma.post.update({
        where: { id: Number(args.id) },
        data: {
          published: true,
        },
      })
    },
    createUser: (parent, args) => {
      return prisma.user.create({
        data: {
          email: args.data.email,
          name: args.data.name,
          posts: {
            create: args.data.posts,
          },
        },
      })
    },
  },
  User: {
    posts: (parent, args) => {
      return prisma.user
        .findOne({
          where: { id: parent.id },
        })
        .posts()
    },
  },
  Post: {
    author: (parent, args) => {
      return prisma.post
        .findOne({
          where: { id: parent.id },
        })
        .author()
    },
  },
}

module.exports = {
  resolvers,
  typeDefs,
}
```

Here is the project on GitHub: https://github.com/DaFaack/prisma-graphql.git

The only files in my .gitignore are node_modules and .env

Comment: Can you share your PostCreateInput file as that has the error as i can see in the logs.

Comment: I added the whole schema.js file with all resolvers and typeDefs.
I don't have a file called PostCreateInput in my filetree.

Comment: If after adding the new field "test" in local it was working then try importing PostCreateInput from @prisma/client and see if it has that field.

Comment: How do I import that? Just type "
import { PostCreateInput } from "@prisma/client"" at the top of my schema.js file?

Comment: I think it has something to do with your .env file. Try to check if you are using the right `.env` for local & deployed/production application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that there is a mismatch between the client you are using and the change you just did in the schema so you would need to generate the client so it's in sync with `npx prisma generate`.

Comment: I tried to do that but its not working, prisma is already installed.
Here is the Project: https://github.com/DaFaack/prisma-graphql.git

Answer (score 0):

awd, i have checkout your code and i can see i am able to create mutation.  As you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

Commands run: 
`npm i` 
`npx prisma migrate dev`
`npm run start`

Comment: Yes like I said the code works for me as well on my localhost. But as soon as I try to connect to my PostgreSQL Database hosted on DigitalOcean it stops working.

Comment: Did you ran "npx prisma migrate deploy" post deploying to DigitalOcean, so your migrations are run in your digital ocean database.

Comment: Yes I did that and I also connected with pgAdmin and saw that the "test" collumn got succesfully created.
So the migration works but something else is probably wrong.
Also my GitHub repository is having everything it needs.
It just doesn't make sense why it's not working.